# brackets and minus in TeXForm or TraditionalForm

Tags: latex

```
-Subscript[\[Gamma],a]*Subscript[\[Rho],1,4]//TeXForm
```

gives me this

```
\rho _{1,4} \left(-\gamma _a\right)
```

Is there a way to get Latex output without brackets? I want minus at the beginning.

-\rho _{1,4} \gamma _a

This is only part of  very large expression.

Comment: Apply `HoldForm` before applying `TeXForm`.

Comment: Thank you for answering, it works like this

TeXForm[HoldForm[-Subscript[\[Gamma], a]*Subscript[\[Rho], 1, 4]]]


but this is problem 

pp=-Subscript[\[Gamma],a]*Subscript[\[Rho],1,4]

TeXForm[HoldForm[pp]]
gives me 

\text{pp}

do I have to copy-paste inside TeXForm[HoldForm[...]] every time?

Comment: You can inject into HoldForm using With. `With[{a=b}, HoldForm[a]]` gives `HoldForm[b]`.

Comment: great, that works

With[{pp = -Subscript[\[Gamma], a]*Subscript[\[Rho], 1, 4]}, 
 TeXForm[HoldForm[pp]]]

but this too
pp = -Subscript[\[Gamma], a]*Subscript[\[Rho], 1, 4]
TeXForm[StandardForm[pp]]

thanks a lot :)